# Finding the first 20 prime numbers in a set of numbers

Tags: algorithm

I am searching for an algorithm to find the first 20 prime numbers in a set of numbers.

My first idea is to explore the naive tests of primality. More precisely using the fact that all integers are of the for 6k+i with k  integer and i = -2,-1,0,1,2,3, primes are of the form 6k+-1 and that we just have to test numbers non greater then $sqrt n$ to test if n is prime.

But dont have many ideas about how actually do it in not too slow way for a given set of numbers (not necessarily consecutive).

Could someone give a help please?

Comment: How big is `k`. It's quite crucial. If `k` is not enormous, just prepare a lookup table. If not, test if eratosthenes sieve is fast enough.

Comment: This is likely to be closed as too broad here. You might want to first build a working program yourself and if you find that it's too slow then post it to [codereview.se] for suggestions.

Comment: Also a definition of "not too slow" would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can spare a few hundred megabytes, consider storing all primes that fit into `int` into a file. Then test or look them up at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In my words, to test a number for being prime:

```
$prime = True
for loop (var = $i, from 2 -> sqrt(number)){
   If number % $i = 0 {
      $prime = False // return 0
   }
}
```

If I didn't understand your question, please tell me, and I'll delete the answer..